# My method did not add my file into my list although no error

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my class that after each file choose add the file to my list and from the main form raise event that update my ListBox and add the file into my ListBox.

when i am choosing 2 files i can see (with the debugger) that the `add method` add the first file and my list updated but after the second file pass the add method the list.count remained still 1.

```
public class ListboxFile
{
    public delegate void OnFileAdd(string file);
    public event OnFileAdd OnFileAddEvent;
    private static List<string> _files;

    public ListboxFile()
    {
        _files = new List<string>();
    }

    public void add(string file)
    {
        _files.Add(file);
        OnFileAddEvent(file);
    }

    public void remove(string file)
    {
        if (_files.Contains(file))
        {
            _files.Remove(file);
        }
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        _files.Clear();
    }

    public List<string> list
    {
        get { return _files; }
    }
}
```

from the main form (add files button click):

```
private void btnAddfiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #region file filter
    string fileToAdd = string.Empty;
    System.IO.Stream stream;
    OpenFileDialog thisDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    thisDialog.InitialDirectory = (lastPath.Length > 0 ? lastPath : "c:\\");
    thisDialog.Filter = "(*.snoop, *.pcap, *.cap, *.net, *.pcapng, *.5vw, *.bfr, *.erf, *.tr1)" +
        "|*.snoop; *.pcap; *.cap; *.net; *.pcapng; *.5vw; *.bfr; *.erf; *.tr1|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*";
    thisDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
    thisDialog.RestoreDirectory = false;
    thisDialog.Multiselect = true;
    thisDialog.Title = "Please Select Source File";
    #endregion

    if (thisDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (thisDialog.FileNames.Length > 0)
        {
            lastPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(thisDialog.FileNames[0]);
        }

        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork +=
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            foreach (String file in thisDialog.FileNames)
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((stream = thisDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                    {
                        int numberOfFiles = thisDialog.SafeFileNames.Length;
                        using (stream)
                        {
                            ListboxFile lbf = new ListboxFile();
                            lbf.OnFileAddEvent += lbf_OnFileAddEvent;
                            lbf.checkFile(file);
                            lastPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(thisDialog.FileNames[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        };

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
            (s3, e3) =>
            {

            });

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

private void lbf_OnFileAddEvent(string file)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {                    
            listBoxFiles.Items.Add(file);
            , listBoxFiles.Items.Count.ToString("#,##0")));
            if (listBoxFiles.Items.Count != 0)
                listBoxFiles.SetSelected(listBoxFiles.Items.Count - 1, true);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        listBoxFiles.Items.Add(file);
        if (listBoxFiles.Items.Count != 0)
            listBoxFiles.SetSelected(listBoxFiles.Items.Count - 1, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: how you *call* this code ?

Comment: sorry but you have a few things in here that don't make sense

Comment: Can you include your 'OnFileAddEvent' handler ? Also check the trigger point of 'clear' method. I suspect it is getting called either at OnFileAddEvent or after/before binding. I am guessing.

Comment: This class should do its works (more or less), the only critical point is the use of the event without checking if it has been set. To understand why you have always one element is necessary to see the code that use an instance of this class

Comment: see my update, what doesn't make sense ?

Comment: Try examining the error in your RunWorkerCompleted event: `e3.Error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare and initialize the instance of ListBoxFile inside the foreach loop.
At every loop you reinitialize the instance and thus you loose the previous add

A fast fix, move the declaration and initialization of the ListboxFile instance outside the loop (also the subscription to the event)

```
.....
ListboxFile lbf = new ListboxFile();
lbf.OnFileAddEvent += lbf_OnFileAddEvent;
foreach (String file in thisDialog.FileNames)
{
  .....
```

and by the way, you call `lbf.checkFile(file);`, did you mean `lbf.Add(file)` right?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `lbf.checkFile(file);` but I do not see that method in your class definition. Maybe inside that method you are not firing `OnFileAddEvent`?